# Inheritance and association in SQL

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5

I have two tables:

```
create table [Customer]
(
    [Id] int primary key identity not null,
    [Type] int not null check([Type >= 0 and [Type] <= 2)
    -- other columns
)
create table [Partial Record]
(
    [Id] int primary key identity not null,
    [Student Id] int references [Customer]([Id])
)
```

I called [Student Id] because the Customer table has a inheritance, here's the problem:
I want to add a check `[Partial Record]` to make sure that the association has a `"[Type] = 1"` for `[Partial Record]` belongs only to students.

is it possible?

Comment: I've never seen a question here in Portuguese.  You might have better luck if you can translate it into English.

Comment: [Non-English Question Policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: Have you tried inputting data that breaks the rule you expect to be enforced?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably prefer to derive the type from the various 'child' table relationships (so, the fact that you've got that `Partial_Record` makes it a student, you don't need `Customer.type`).  Although, I don't know the 'standard' for these designs.  Oh, and whatever you do, **don't** use spaces in entity names.

Comment: What do the values 0 & 2 represent in the `Type` field? If you are separating Students because they are type 1 then it seems to me you need tables for the other types (which will either include or replace your `Customer` table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding a super key to the `Customer` table, and adding an enforcing foreign key:

```
create table [Customer]
(
    [Id] int primary key identity not null,
    [Type] int not null check([Type] >= 0 and [Type] <= 2)
    ,constraint UQ_Customer_TypeCheck UNIQUE (ID,Type)
)
create table [Partial Record]
(
    [Id] int primary key identity not null,
    [Student Id] int references [Customer]([Id]),
    Type as 1 persisted,
    constraint FK_Partial_TypeCheck FOREIGN KEY ([Student Id],Type) references Customer (ID,Type)
)
```

(I would probably remove `Id` from `[Partial Record]` if each Student should only have one row - just make `[Student Id]` the primary key)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of doing it with triggers using something like: [SQL Server: halt an INSERT in a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915002/sql-server-halt-an-insert-in-a-trigger).  Probably won't be very efficient or performant, but should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200817/243925) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880768/243925)) to similar questions, you can create a [User Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) to check the values in the other table and then write a contraint to call the function.

But as others have commented I would consider changing your tables, if you are able to. A different design would remove the need for the `type` field.